# chosing files to upload on ther server from HTML5 boilerplate

Tags: html, web-hosting, html5boilerplate

i was wondering which files should i upload to my server form the HTML5 boilerplate.zip

i unzipped the HTML5 boilerplate zip and got the following files

```
            .git(hidden)
            .gitattributes
            .gitignore
            .htaccess
            .project
            404.html
            apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
            browserconfig.xml
            CHANGELOG.md
            CONTRIBUTING.md
            crossdomain.xml
            css
            doc
            favicon.ico
            humans.txt
            img
            index.html
            js
            LICENSE.md
            README.md
            robots.txt
            tile-wide.png
            tile.png
```

after i have done my coding and added a few files as per my project, do i upload all of these files to the server?
if yes the what is the use of the .git and other .gitattributes folder and files?

or should i upload only the once which are necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need these:

```
        .htaccess
        404.html
        apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png
        browserconfig.xml
        crossdomain.xml
        css
        doc
        favicon.ico
        humans.txt
        img
        index.html
        js
        robots.txt
        tile-wide.png
        tile.png
```